# Error using subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute the following query :

```
UPDATE TempRH 
    SET TempRH.poids=0
    WHERE TempRH.poids IN (SELECT * 
                                    FROM(
    SELECT MAX(TempRH.poids)as poids,TempRH.utilisateur_id  
    FROM TempRH 
                                             INNER JOIN                                               (SELECT TempRH.utilisateur_id
                                                   FROM TempRH 
                                                   GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id 
                                                   HAVING COUNT(*)>2)t
                                             ON t.utilisateur_id =TempRH.utilisateur_id
                                        GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id  
                                    )x);
```

I get the following error 
**Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Comment: first i would recommand to visibility to use a cte. And the error seems clear, use exists instead of in. I'm not common to this error cause i banned in since a long time for query values :) where exists (...... where temprh.poids = poids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yes your error, but look at the comment :)

You are returing 2 columns from your query, you can only return one column for a in clause.

Remove the ,temprh.utilisateur_id , you don't need it in your select statement

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the post you deleted to how to make your update :

```
declare @temprh table (utilisateur_id int, poids int)
insert into @temprh values (1,10)
insert into @temprh values (1,20)
insert into @temprh values (2,30)
insert into @temprh values (3,40)
insert into @temprh values (3,50)

;with x as (
SELECT utilisateur_id as uu, MAX(TempRH.poids)as pp, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM @temprh as  TempRH
GROUP BY TempRH.utilisateur_id
) 

UPDATE @TempRH 
SET poids=0
WHERE exists (select * from x where x.uu = Utilisateur_id and pp = poids and cnt=2)
```

of course it's an example but i just replaced your table name by a variable to have some data. You want to remove the higher one to 0 right?